# PHP - Can't import CSV

Tags: php

I've followed a tutorial but tried to edit it whilst working.
I can't get my data to go from a csv to my DB
I keep  getting, Problem in importing but n cannot figure out why

hoping someone can help

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "password", "cards");

if (isset($_POST["import"])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into `cards` (`number`,`status`) values ('" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "')";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

            if (! empty($result)) {
                $type = "success";
                $message = "CSV Data Imported into the Database";
            } else {

                $type = "error";
                $message = "Problem in Importing CSV Data";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: it's all good thanks, i thrhew a or die mysql error at the end and it was no default value for a field in the DB. all fixed

Comment: It's good that it works finally. But the way you're doing has a possibility sql injection attack. So you must use `prepare()` and `bind_param()` method as you're using `mysqli` to prevent sql injection.